# GCM + AppEngine - app does not receive push notifications

Tags: android, google-app-engine, push-notification, google-cloud-messaging

I am developing an app client for my appengine server powered with push notification service.
I have already set up and deployed the server part and been able to register my device, but once I send a push notification, it never comes to the app.

I am using Android Studio for both the app and backend and I followed the steps in here: https://github.com/manfredzab/gradle-appengine-templates/tree/master/GcmEndpoints.

AndroidManifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.myapp" >

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name=".MyActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <receiver
            android:name=".GcmBroadcastReceiver"
            android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
                <category android:name="com.example.myapp" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>

        <service android:name=".GcmIntentService" />
    </application>

    <permission
        android:name="com.example.myapp.permission.C2D_MESSAGE"
         />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />
    <!-- <uses-permission android:name="com.example.gcm.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" /> -->
    <uses-permission android:name="com.example.myapp.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.example.myapp.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />

</manifest>
```

MainActivity:

```
package com.example.myapp;

public class MyActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_my);
    new GcmRegistrationAsyncTask().execute(this);
}


@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.my, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
}
```

BroadcastReceiver

```
public class GcmBroadcastReceiver extends WakefulBroadcastReceiver
{
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    // Explicitly specify that GcmIntentService will handle the intent.
    ComponentName comp = new ComponentName(context.getPackageName(),
                                           GcmIntentService.class.getName());
    // Start the service, keeping the device awake while it is launching.
    startWakefulService(context, (intent.setComponent(comp)));
    setResultCode(Activity.RESULT_OK);
    Log.i("blabla","notification received");
}
}
```

IntentService

```
public class GcmIntentService extends IntentService
{

public GcmIntentService() {
    super("GcmIntentService");
}

@Override
protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
    Log.i("blabla", "notification received");
    Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();
    GoogleCloudMessaging gcm = GoogleCloudMessaging.getInstance(this);
    // The getMessageType() intent parameter must be the intent you received
    // in your BroadcastReceiver.
    String messageType = gcm.getMessageType(intent);

    if (extras != null && !extras.isEmpty()) {  // has effect of unparcelling Bundle
        // Since we're not using two way messaging, this is all we really to check for
        if (GoogleCloudMessaging.MESSAGE_TYPE_MESSAGE.equals(messageType)) {
            Logger.getLogger("GCM_RECEIVED").log(Level.INFO, extras.toString());

            showToast(extras.getString("message"));
        }
    }
    GcmBroadcastReceiver.completeWakefulIntent(intent);
}

protected void showToast(final String message) {
    new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()).post(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), message, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    });
}
}
```

MessagingEndpoint:

```
@Api(name = "messaging", version = "v1", namespace = @ApiNamespace(ownerDomain =     "myapp.example.com", ownerName = "myapp.example.com", packagePath=""))
public class MessagingEndpoint {
private static final Logger log = Logger.getLogger(MessagingEndpoint.class.getName());

/** Api Keys can be obtained from the google cloud console */
private static final String API_KEY = System.getProperty("gcm.api.key");

public void sendMessage(@Named("message") String message) throws IOException {
    if(message == null || message.trim().length() == 0) {
        log.warning("Not sending message because it is empty");
        return;
    }
    // crop longer messages
    if (message.length() > 1000) {
        message = message.substring(0, 1000) + "[...]";
    }
    Sender sender = new Sender(API_KEY);
    Message msg = new Message.Builder().addData("message", message).build();
    List<RegistrationRecord> records = ofy().load().type(RegistrationRecord.class).limit(1000).list();
    for(RegistrationRecord record : records) {
        Result result = sender.send(msg, record.getRegId(), 10);
        if (result.getMessageId() != null) {
            log.info("Message sent to " + record.getRegId());
            String canonicalRegId = result.getCanonicalRegistrationId();
            if (canonicalRegId != null) {
                // if the regId changed, we have to update the datastore
                log.info("Registration Id changed for " + record.getRegId() + " updating to " + canonicalRegId);
                record.setRegId(canonicalRegId);
                ofy().save().entity(record).now();
            }
        } else {
            String error = result.getErrorCodeName();
            if (error.equals(Constants.ERROR_NOT_REGISTERED)) {
                log.warning("Registration Id " + record.getRegId() + " no longer registered with GCM, removing from datastore");
                // if the device is no longer registered with Gcm, remove it from the datastore
                ofy().delete().entity(record).now();
            }
            else {
                log.warning("Error when sending message : " + error);
            }
        }
    }
}
}
```

OfyService:

```
public class OfyService {

static {
    ObjectifyService.register(RegistrationRecord.class);
}

public static Objectify ofy() {
    return ObjectifyService.ofy();
}

public static ObjectifyFactory factory() {
    return ObjectifyService.factory();
}
}
```

Registration Endpoint

```
@Api(name = "registration", version = "v1",
 namespace = @ApiNamespace(ownerDomain = "myapp.example.com", ownerName = "myapp.example.com", packagePath = ""))
public class RegistrationEndpoint
{

private static final Logger log = Logger.getLogger(RegistrationEndpoint.class.getName());

/**
 * Register a device to the backend
 *
 * @param regId The Google Cloud Messaging registration Id to add
 */
@ApiMethod(name = "register")
public void registerDevice(@Named("regId") String regId)
{
    if (findRecord(regId) != null)
    {
        log.info("Device " + regId + " already registered, skipping register");
        return;
    }
    RegistrationRecord record = new RegistrationRecord();
    record.setRegId(regId);
    ofy().save().entity(record).now();
}

/**
 * Unregister a device from the backend
 *
 * @param regId The Google Cloud Messaging registration Id to remove
 */
@ApiMethod(name = "unregister")
public void unregisterDevice(@Named("regId") String regId)
{
    RegistrationRecord record = findRecord(regId);
    if (record == null)
    {
        log.info("Device " + regId + " not registered, skipping unregister");
        return;
    }
    ofy().delete().entity(record).now();
}

/**
 * Return a collection of registered devices
 *
 * @param count The number of devices to list
 * @return a list of Google Cloud Messaging registration Ids
 */
@ApiMethod(name = "listDevices")
public CollectionResponse<RegistrationRecord> listDevices(@Named("count") int count)
{
    List<RegistrationRecord> records = ofy().load().type(RegistrationRecord.class).limit(count).list();
    return CollectionResponse.<RegistrationRecord>builder().setItems(records).build();
}

private RegistrationRecord findRecord(String regId)
{
    return ofy().load().type(RegistrationRecord.class).filter("regId", regId).first().now();
}

}
```

RegistrationRecord

```
@Entity
public class RegistrationRecord {

@Id
Long id;

@Index
private String regId;
// you can add more fields...

public RegistrationRecord() {}

public String getRegId() {
    return regId;
}

public void setRegId(String regId) {
    this.regId = regId;
}
}
```

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Hello, Google Cloud Messaging!</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet"     href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet"     href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js" >    </script>
    <script src="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/js/bootstrap.min.js">    </script>
</head>
<body role="document" style="padding-top: 70px;">
<div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="navbar-header">
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Hello, Google Cloud Messaging!</a>
        </div>
        <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                <li class="dropdown">
                    <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-    toggle="dropdown">Documentation <b class="caret"></b></a>
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                        <li><a     href="https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/">Google App Engine</a></li>
                        <li><a     href="https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/endpoints/">Google Cloud     Endpoints</a></li>
                        <li><a href="http://developer.android.com/google/gcm/">Google Cloud Messaging</a></li>
                        <li><a href="https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/gradle-appengine-templates/tree/master/GcmEndpoints">Connecting your Android application to this backend</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li><a href="/_ah/api/explorer">Google Cloud Endpoints API Explorer</a></li>
                <li><a href="https://console.developers.google.com">Google Developers Console</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="container theme-showcase" role="main">
<!--
  Output from GCM call.
-->
<div class="alert alert-success" style="visibility: collapse;" id="outputAlert"></div>

<!--
  A form that takes a message text and submits it to "messaging" Endpoints API,
  access to this Endpoints API is enabled once the client is loaded below.
-->
<div class="jumbotron">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-12">
            <h1>Hello, Google Cloud Messaging!</h1>
            <p>Enter your message below and press "Send Message" button to send it over Google Cloud Messaging to all registered devices.</p>
            <form>
                <div class="input-group">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control input-lg" placeholder="Message text" id="messageTextInput" />
                      <span class="input-group-btn">
                         <button class="btn btn-default btn-primary btn-group btn-lg" type="submit" id="sendMessageButton">Send Message &raquo;</button>
                      </span>
                </div>
            </form>
            <br/>
            <p>If you need step-by-step instructions for connecting your Android application to this backend module, see <a href="https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/gradle-appengine-templates/tree/master/GcmEndpoints">"App Engine Backend with Google Cloud Messaging" template documentation</a>.</p>
            <p>
                    <small>
                    For more information about Google App Engine for Java, check out the <a href="https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/">App Engine documentation</a>.<br />
                    To learn more about Google Cloud Endpoints, see <a href="https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/endpoints/">Cloud Endpoints documentation</a>.<br />
                    Similarly, for more information about Google Cloud Messaging, see     <a href="http://developer.android.com/google/gcm/">Cloud Messaging documentation</a>.<br />
                    If you'd like to access your generated Google Cloud Endpoints APIs directly, see the <a href="/_ah/api/explorer">Cloud Endpoints API Explorer</a>.
                    </small>
                </p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
// A function that attaches a "Send Message" button click handler
function enableClick() {
  document.getElementById('sendMessageButton').onclick = function() {
    var message = document.getElementById('messageTextInput').value;
    if (!message) {
      message = '(Empty message)';
    }

    gapi.client.messaging.messagingEndpoint.sendMessage({'message': message}).execute(
      function(response) {
        var outputAlertDiv = document.getElementById('outputAlert');
        outputAlertDiv.style.visibility = 'visible';

        if (response && response.error) {
          outputAlertDiv.className = 'alert alert-danger';
          outputAlertDiv.innerHTML = '<b>Error Code:</b> ' + response.error.code + ' [' + response.error.message +']';
        }
        else {
          outputAlertDiv.className = 'alert alert-success';
          outputAlertDiv.innerHTML = '<b>Success:</b> Message \"' + message + '\" sent to all registered devices!</h2>';
        }
      }
    );
    return false;
  }
}

// This is called initially
function init() {
  var apiName = 'messaging'
  var apiVersion = 'v1'
  // set the apiRoot to work on a deployed app and locally
  var apiRoot = '//' + window.location.host + '/_ah/api';
  var callback = function() {
    enableClick();
  }
  gapi.client.load(apiName, apiVersion, callback, apiRoot);
}
  </script>
<!--
 Load the Google APIs Client Library for JavaScript
 More info here : https://developers.google.com/api-client-    library/javascript/reference/referencedocs
-->
<script src="https://apis.google.com/js/client.js?onload=init"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

appengine-web.xml

```
<appengine-web-app xmlns="http://appengine.google.com/ns/1.0">
<application>app-name-from-developers-console</application>
<version>1</version>
<threadsafe>true</threadsafe>

<system-properties>
    <property name="java.util.logging.config.file" value="WEB-INF/logging.properties"/>


    <property name="gcm.api.key" value="gcm-SERVER-api-key-from-dev-console"/>
</system-properties>
```

I don't know what more to add, the backend seems to work well, since the registration has been successfully proceeded. I don't get any errors, nothing. What am I missing? There must be just a little mistake somewhere and I can't spot it. I assume that there is everything well established for sending the push notifications right away since it was all generated. I have my service api key set correctly and I have set IPS to any IP allowed.

Comment: Do you get a successfull response from gcm server?

Comment: For the push message? Where should I look?

Comment: A couple things, are you using the local development server or deployed to appspot.  Also when sending the message open your browsers development tools and check to see if you notice anything funny.

Comment: Appspot. I´ll look into into later on and let you know about the "funny" part.

Comment: make sure you're using https explicitly, some older versions of the appengine template's javascript pages don't handle this well.  You need to make sure the endpoints request goes over https and the endpoints javascript stuff extracts the address from the address bar.

Comment: You didn't include your server code, but you should be getting a response from Google for your Http request.  Can you post that response?

Comment: I added some server code. If you are missing anything specific, I will add it to the post. Here is the error 403 I am getting from the server http://ge.tt/55LA9po1/v/0?c

Comment: Hahah!!! Such a stupid mistake. I only needed to change http to https in the web interface for GCM. anyway....thanks for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only problem was that I had http in the main page url for GCM instead of https. Changing this solved my problem.

In index.html I changed

```
// This is called initially
function init() {
  var apiName = 'messaging'
  var apiVersion = 'v1'
  // set the apiRoot to work on a deployed app and locally
  var apiRoot = '//' + window.location.host + '/_ah/api';

  var callback = function() {
    enableClick();
  }
  gapi.client.load(apiName, apiVersion, callback, apiRoot);
}
```

to

```
// This is called initially
function init() {
  var apiName = 'messaging'
  var apiVersion = 'v1'
  // set the apiRoot to work on a deployed app and locally
  var apiRoot = 'https://' + window.location.host + '/_ah/api';

  var callback = function() {
    enableClick();
  }
  gapi.client.load(apiName, apiVersion, callback, apiRoot);
}
```